# Strong Coupling Model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, second-quantization

I found a Hamiltonian that keeps appearing when reading about the strong coupling regime. For better understanding I would like to know where it comes from exactly.

I do of course understand the $H_0$ term.

$a_k$ is the photon annihiliation operator and $b_k$ would be the annihilaton operator in a 2-state system.

$$H=H_0+H_{int}$$
$$H_0=\sum_k \hbar \omega_{L} a_k^+ a_k+\sum_k \hbar \omega b_k^+ b_k$$

What I do not completely understand is the $H_{int}$ part.

$$H_{int}=\sum_k \hbar \left[i\Omega_k \left(a_k^+ b_k-a_k b_k^++a_kb_{-k}-a_k^+b_{-k}^+ \right)+D_k \left(a_k^+ a_k+a_k a_k^+ +a_k a_{-k} +a_k^+ a_{-k}^+\right)\right]$$

I already tried using the Hamiltonian for a charged particle in the electromagnetic field

$$H=\frac{1}{2m}\left(p-qA\right)^2+qV$$

and replacing the operators using their representations in terms of ladder operators but unfortunately I did not quite get there.

I would very much appreciate any input on this topic.

Thank you!

Edit:

References
http://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.72.115303 (Equations 6,7 and 8)

http://www.springer.com/de/book/9783540675204 (Equation 2.11)

Comment: Do you have a reference ?

Comment: " $b_k$ would be the annihilation operator in a 2-state system": No, and perhaps this is the problem you are having. The authors' definition of the $b_k$-s is as weak _bosonic_ excitations resulting from (strong?) fermionic interactions. Write the mode momenta carefully and it should work, provided you keep the terms resulting from $A^2$, as the authors explain (first paper, paragraphs after Eq.(8)). Neglect terms in $b_kb_{-k}$ etc as usual.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! As you might have noticed I am not yet too experienced in such things. In what way does it make a difference what $b_k$ is exactly as long as it fulfills the commutation relation for bosons (in a pure mathematical way)?

Could you maybe give me an Ansatz to explain what you mean by keeping the terms form $A^2$?